# MS Visual Studio Lightswitch flipswitch control sometimes does have displayed default value

Tags: visual-studio-2013, lightswitch-2013, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I have an interesting issue with a LightSwitch app I am maintaining, there is room for confusion so will try and explain at length and answer any clarifying questions.

I have a LightSwitch AddEdit screen using the default 'Flip Switch' control for Boolean values in a table, set to Yes/No Option (so shows Yes or No as values, actually saves 0 or 1), when creating a new entry, the control shows 'No' by default. The issue is that depending on what permission the user has the control behaves differently, either:

1) the expected/desired behaviour: The flip switch is set to 'No' by default and if the screen is saved without touching it 'No' is saved to the database (What the user sees and what is saved is consistent, a flip switch is never NULL).

2) The unexpected behaviour: The flip switch looks like it is set to 'No', but when user attempts to save the screen, gets a warning "Error: Cannot continue. There are validation errors on the page" because there are Boolean values that do not allow NULL (the relevant flip switches are highlighted with 'This field is required') the user can toggle the flip switch control to Yes and back to No, at which point the screen will save (touching the control seems to set it to a value from NULL), but disturbingly the other flip switches that do allow NULL are saved as NULL instead of the 'No' they show on the screen, this is confusing and problematic and will require users to re-enter all the NULL entries once I fix this bug.

The troubleshooting I had done so far shows that the behaviour is contingent on what LightSwitch Access Control permission the user has set, if they are in one group(SystemAdministrator) they get behaviour 1 in another(DatabaseOperators) they get 2.

It also appears contingent on being an 'add' rather than an 'edit' if adding a new row as a SystemAdministrator, the data will be added as behaviour 1. if editing an existing entry you get behaviour 2 as both permissions.

I tested commenting out the VB code that filters the permissions for the data source for this table (TableName_CanRead, TableName_CanWrite, TableName_CanInsert, TableName_CanUpdate, TableName_CanDelete, TableName_CanExecute, TableName_Filter) as that seemed to be a likely point of difference and it did *not* change the behaviour.

I am hoping that someone more familiar with the LightSwitch environment will be able to point me to another likely place where this issue is coming from and give some hints on where to look or further troubleshooting steps. 
I currently can't see how the permission group is effecting the flip switch control behaviour so markedly

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for your scenario in my opinion is the following:

on the screen created code block, use the following code for each switch:

```
myapp.SCREENNAME.created = function (screen) {
    if (screen.TABLENAME.theFlipSwitchA == null) {
        screen.TABLENAME.theFlipSwitchA = false;
    }

    if (screen.TABLENAME.theFlipSwitchB == null) {
        screen.TABLENAME.theFlipSwitchB = true;
    }
}
```

This will ensure the null values are replaced with the correct TRUE or FALSE values at the start, and will only change if the user changes them.

**In Addition**

There are 2 views available for a flip switch aswell being Yes/No and On/Off, which can be accessed on the properties of the selected Flip Switch:

[image]

One thing to make sure is you use the **Data** **Binding** property to specify the value, not the Name like you usually would on a forms application for example.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a decent work around thank you, I would need to go add this code for all flip switches on all screens to be sure they don't insert NULL which seems like a lot of messing around, but if that is what has to be done...

Comment: As side question can I use similar code work to set the appearance of the flip switch to Yes (where that is a more useful default than No) in the:

`myapp.myscreen.flipswitch_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    // Write code here.
    screen.TABLENAME.theFlipSwitch = true;
};`

And if I do that, would that solve the problem of NULL? or do I need to also check for null in beforeapplychanges as well?

Comment: I have changed the answer above to better suit your scenario, the values are changed on the screen created event now, and I have added in the false and true options also. it is a pain having to do it for each switch I agree, but at least it works :) and yes you are right to assume changing it to true will work. by doing it on the created even this means when the screen loads, those options are automatically displayed correctly

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tested with this: 
`myapp.AddEditiRVRTC.created = function (screen) {
    // Explicitly set switches to avoid stealth nulls.
    if (screen.iRVRTC.rvrtc_20_valid == null) {
        screen.iRVRTC.rvrtc_20_valid = false;
    }

    if (screen.iRVRTC.rvrtc_30_valid == null) {
        screen.iRVRTC.rvrtc_30_valid = false;
    }
};` I am getting error: "Cannot read property 'rvrtc_20_valid' of undefined" Intellisense shows the member variable correctly in the first istance, but later lines it says unable to determine accurate completion list. So not sure what is happening there.

Comment: in terms of the Intellisense, this has always happened as far as I can tell, where it doesn't display the completion list after x amount of code lines, which is annoying! looking at that code I don't see why it doesn't work if your sure the variable names are correct. The only thing I can think of is your following the Name convention rather than the Data Binding, ill add the image above

Comment: Interestingly I can get it to work with the same code in `myapp.AddEditiRVRTC.beforeApplyChanges = function (screen)` So can use that. Would love to know what is stopping .created from working though.

Comment: I would like to know aswell, I don't mind taking a quick look at the program if you want me to, to see if I can work out the issue?

Comment: the only alternative is add a custom button called save, and on the execute part, add all the code you want at the top to change the null values to false, and the add myapp.commitChanges() to see if that works?

Comment: What would be the best way for you to have a quick look? Could do remote access of some sort, though it would probably have to be next week sometime.

Comment: well you could upload the project to drop box, or team viewer is the safest option alternatively, unless you have another preference.and thats fine with me, whenever best suits.